# ASP.Net Session Timeout: Why 20 minutes used as default?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-timeout

In ASP.Net the default Session Timeout is set to 20 minutes. Why so? Is there any specific reason behind it?

Answer (score 7):

> It should not be set higher than 20 minutes (except in special cases) because every open session is holding onto memory.

From [Session.Timeout on MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473.aspx)

Note they also give an explanation for the minimum

> It should also not be set lower than 4 minutes because clients rarely respond within that time resulting in a loss of session state.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Well:
10 minutes is too fast.
30 minutes is too long.
15, 25 minutes - number is not pretty.
So, they decided on 20 :P

There is no magical meaning in number 20. It is just decided to be an optimal and prettiest value for session timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fewer users, or if you save the session state to a DB, a larger timeout won't consume too many resources.