# what is unit of session timeout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Can any body please tell me unit of session time which we specify in ASP.Net Web.config in sessionstate,

Is it in minute,second or miliseconds?

Thanks

Answer (score 36):

```
<sessionState 
    timeout="number of minutes">  
<sessionState/>
```

Answer (score 7):

[HttpSessionState.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx)

Gets and sets the amount of time, **in minutes**, allowed between requests before the session-state provider terminates the session.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

Unit is **Minutes**.

This is specified in the msdn for [ASP.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) under the section 'Configuring Session State'.

Answer (score 4):

### Session timeout is in minutes

---

Answer (score 1):

Default session time is 20 minutes  [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx)

Here is one of the way

1.http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/06/09/ah-ah-ah-ah-staying-alive-staying-alive.aspx

Check this Solution

2.[how to avoid session timeout in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5354541/1053241)

3.https://stackoverflow.com/a/412502/1053241

Answer (score 0):

Use `<sessionState timeout="100"/>` tag for session timeout Property

100 is in minutes