# how to avoid session timeout in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

What should I write in web config file in asp.net so that my session time is extended. and please tell me the exact location where should I place the code in web config

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are trying to stop the session from timeing out all the time you can do this rather than increasing the session timeout.

KeepAlive.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="KeepAlive.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages.KeepAlive" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ OutputCache Location="None" VaryByParam="None" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    KEEP ALIVE
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep Alive.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Page to keep the session alive
    /// </summary>
    public partial class KeepAlive : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //- EVENTS ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Events

        /// <summary>
        /// Page Load
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object</param>
        /// <param name="e">args</param>
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Add refresh header to refresh the page 60 seconds before session timeout
                Response.AddHeader("Refresh", Convert.ToString((Session.Timeout * 60) - 60));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        #endregion Events

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
}
```

Then in your master page create an iFrame that refreshes to keep the session alive

```
<iframe id="Defib" src="KeepAlive.aspx" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" runat="server">
</iframe>
```

Comment: that works just fine for me , I had this prob when the session gets timeout and then all the application stops , with this it keeps refreshing and working just as expected

Comment: But wouldn't this force a postback every time?

Comment: @Fernando68 - it causes a postback in the hidden iFrame, the rest of the page is unaffected. I use an ajax callback to a codebehind webmethod these days however

Answer (score 7):

Just change the timeout to the minutes you want the session to last

```
<!--<configuration>-->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="20" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify session time out in web.config file,
can also use timespan--20 minutes is default, also The timeout attribute cannot be set to a value that is greater than 525,601 minutes (1 year) for the in-process and state-server modes.

```
<sessionState 
    mode="[Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]"
    timeout="number of minutes"
    cookieName="session identifier cookie name"
    cookieless=
         "[true|false|AutoDetect|UseCookies|UseUri|UseDeviceProfile]"
    regenerateExpiredSessionId="[True|False]"
    sqlConnectionString="sql connection string"
    sqlCommandTimeout="number of seconds"
    allowCustomSqlDatabase="[True|False]"
    useHostingIdentity="[True|False]"
    stateConnectionString="tcpip=server:port"
    stateNetworkTimeout="number of seconds"
    customProvider="custom provider name">
    <providers>...</providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the amount of time a session can be idle before it is discarded by adjusting the timeout attribute within the  Element.

Remember that the timeout value is set in minutes.

> **timeout:**Specifies the number of minutes a
>   session can be idle before it is
>   abandoned. The timeout attribute
>   cannot be set to a value that is
>   greater than 525,601 minutes (1 year)
>   for the in-process and state-server
>   modes.

For reference please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

See the [HttpSessionState.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

You can change session timeout value in web.config.

If the desired session timeout is 60 minutes, markup code in web.config should look like this:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="60" />
```