# Session TimeOut even though system is in use

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I am using an MVC application and I have set the session timeout to 100 minutes.

The problem is that the session timeout occurs even though I am using the system. Is it possible to prevent a session timeout when the system is in use.

I'm using this code to set the session timeout:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="100">
</sessionState>
```

Please correct me if I am using the wrong method, thank you.

Comment: The Timeout property cannot be set to a value greater than 525,600 minutes (1 year). The default value is 20 minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to avoid session timeout in web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354541/how-to-avoid-session-timeout-in-web-config)