# asp.net postback timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have an aspx page with a few textboxes and a submit button.
Once the submit button is clicked an xml file is created from the table/textboxes on the screen.

That works fine if doing it right away but if you click the button after 20 mins or so the page errors out.

I have:

```
 <location path="Default.aspx">
        <system.web>
          <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000000000"/>
        </system.web>
      </location>
```

in web.config and `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="1000000000" />` on the aspx page but it still times out after around 20 mins or so.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's likely timing out at 20 minutes because that's the default session timeout. Nonetheless, any operation running for 20 minutes is WAY TOO LONG...

Comment: Another reason could be IIS which recycles app pool after 20 minutes idle by default.

Comment: Does your operation take 20 minutes or is there an input mask where the user usually takes longer than that to input his data before posting the data?

Comment: No operation is actually happening, its just that people would leave the window open for a long time and when they go to put in the data in the textbox and click submit (after 1 hour or smore at time) it errors out. I am using session vars so maybe it tries to access them after 20 mins when its timed out?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default session time is 20mins  [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx)

Here is one of the way

1.http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/06/09/ah-ah-ah-ah-staying-alive-staying-alive.aspx

Check this Solution

2.[how to avoid session timeout in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5354541/1053241)

3.https://stackoverflow.com/a/412502/1053241

Comment: Its odd, I've changed the seesion timeout in IIS to 60 mins but it still has not worked. Link 1. did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config you more than likely have

```
  <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

You shouldn't really extend your session timeout beyond this though

[How to set session timeout more than 20 min.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725925/how-to-set-session-timeout-more-than-20-min)
This post explains all the relevant places to check your session timeout

Also when you come to deploy your application remember to check the IIS timeout configuration

Comment: I'd bet OP doesn't have that if he/she doesn't know why it's timing out at 20 minutes. 20 minutes is the default InProc timeout period, though, so it makes sense that it has something to do with session.

Comment: True, though I thought SessionState was added to web.config by default. I'm going to go check...

Comment: I have changed Time-out (in minutes) on the Session State page in IIS from 20 to 60 mins and will check if that resolves it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Session is over, Try to set the SessionTimeOut, or write a JavaScript function to send an AJAX request time by time to keep the Session alive.
But I really don't think you're on the right way with that, if the Session is over you should redirect to the login page.

Comment: Its an intranet site, no need for login, its NTLM.

Answer (score 1):

I am setting this at individual page and button click event. Seems to do the trick if you do not want a application wide timeout change in config.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 90000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example to keep a session alive: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=453

Answer (score 0):

Also rather than extending your session you could just warn the users that they are about to be timed out of the system and ask them if you wish to continue using the site

http://programmerramblings.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/aspnet-session-timeout-control-with.html

This control lets you do that